# force.com streaming API

Tags: api, streaming, force.com

I am trying the [Force.com Streaming API demo](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/api_streaming.pdf) and I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault>
        <faultcode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</faultcode>
        <faultstring>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Element type &quot;soapenv:Envelope&quot; must be followed by either attribute specifications, &quot;&gt;&quot; or &quot;/&gt;&quot;.   </faultstring>
        <detail>
            <sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">   
                <sf:exceptionCode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</sf:exceptionCode>
                <sf:exceptionMessage>Element type &quot;soapenv:Envelope&quot; must be followed by either attribute specifications, &quot;&gt;&quot; or &quot;/&gt;&quot;.</sf:exceptionMessage>
            </sf:UnexpectedErrorFault>  
        </detail> 
    </soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 22 has a misplaced [double quote](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/api_streaming.pdf) that is not caught by your compiler.

Replace this code:

```
private static final String ENV_START =
"
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
         + "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " +
         "xmlns:urn='urn:partner.soap.sforce.com'><soapenv:Body>";
```

With this code:

```
private static final String ENV_START =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"
    + "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " +
         "xmlns:urn='urn:partner.soap.sforce.com'><soapenv:Body>";
```

Comment: @Thys Andries Michels  Have you tried my answer? This change I suggested worked for me temporarily, however it now appears that the problem has returned. I am going to delete my answer until I can further investigate this error.

Comment: I'm thinking that tutorial is outdated. I am trying the following tutorial instead an I will report if it works. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API